# SQL query for retrieve data from three tables

Tags: sql

I have three tables:

**tbl_ProjectsUsers**

```
ProjectId
companyUserID
```

**tbl_Projects**

```
ProjectId
CompanyClientId
```

**tbl_CompanyClient**

```
CompanyClientName
CompanyClientId
```

How can I retrieve ProjectID,CompanyClientID,CompanyClientName from three tables Using @companyUserID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a join between the three tables:

```
SELECT t1.ProjectId,
       t1.companyUserID,
       COALESCE(t2.CompanyClientId, 'NA'),
       COALESCE(t3.CompanyClientName, 'NA')
FROM tbl_ProjectsUsers t1
LEFT JOIN tbl_Projects t2
    ON t1.ProjectId = t2.ProjectId
LEFT JOIN tbl_Company_Client t3
    ON t2.CompanyClientId = t3.CompanyClientId
WHERE t1.companyUserID = <some_value>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    a.ProjectId, b.CompanyClientId, c.CompanyClientName 
from 
    tbl_ProjectsUsers as a 
inner join 
    tbl_Projects as b on a.ProjectId = b.ProjectId
inner join 
    tbl_CompanyClient as c on b.CompanyClientId = c.CompanyClientId 
where 
    a.companyUserID = id
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

**Here is the Solution you Requested:**

```
Declare @CompanyUserID   int = 10       --no idea what the data type is but i assume an integer.

Select
    u.CompanyUserID
,   p.ProjectID
,   c.CompanyClientID
,   c.CompanyClientName
FROM
            tbl_ProjectUsers  u
    JOIN    tbl_Projects      p   on u.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
    JOIN    tbl_CompanyClient c   on p.CompanyClientID = c.CompanyClientID
WHERE
    u.CompanyUserIDin (@CompanyUserID)
```

If you change the Variable number (10) it will return different results. I assume you have it set as a Int but it could be a string
if it is a string something like the following should work

```
Declare @CompanyUserID varchar(max) = 'UserID'
```

You will need to determine the join types more specifically but in T-SQL this works for me. I would recommend eithier Inner Joins or Left Joins for this one, however using just JOIN will work sufficiently

POST NOTE - I see you updated your post so now it makes sense for the 3 tables